# How to reset yasnippet default snippet file

Tags: yasnippet

for some reason the content of my default +new-snippet+ file has changed from

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: 
# key: 
# --
```

to

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
    # name: 
        # key: 
    # --
```

The whitespace breaks the snippet compilation it would seem. I was wondering if it is possible to reset the default snippet file text so that I don't have to manually fix it each time?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the value of `yas-new-snippet-default` to its default value by adding the following to your config.

```
(setq yas-new-snippet-default "# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: $1
# key: ${2:${1:$(yas--key-from-desc yas-text)}}
# --
$0`(yas-escape-text yas-selected-text)`")
```

Nevertheless, having to add this to your config is annoying, try to update Yasnippet and/or Emacs and make sure no made no mistake with your Yasnippet configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Unfortunately for some reason the weird tabs still persist even when I use this in my config and after updating yasnippet. Do you know where I can check my Yasnippet config?

Comment: You can put a copy of your Yasnippet configuration at the end of your post to allow people to correct it if necessary. Also, you can read [Yasnippet documentation](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/)  and [known issues](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues?q=label%3Asupport).